# Do block elements ignore floating elements?

Tags: html, css, css-float

[W3C states](https://www.w3.org/TR/2011/REC-CSS2-20110607/visuren.html#floats) that:

> Since a float is not in the flow, non-positioned **block boxes created before and after the float box flow vertically as if the float did not exist**. However, the current and subsequent line boxes created next to the float are shortened as necessary to make room for the margin box of the float.

This work as expected with `div`s:

```css
#a
{
 width: 100px;
 height: 100px;
 background-color: blue;
 float: left;
}

#b
{
 width: 200px;
 height: 200px;
 display: block;
 border: 1px solid black;
 background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<body>
 <div id=a></div>
 
 <div id=b></div>
</body>
```

Here the red `div` is block-level element, therefore it's ignoring the floating one. (if I changed red one to `display: inline-block` it would appear next to floating one)

But, if I apply `display: block` to an image ,it won't ignore the floating `div`, Why?

```css
#a
{
 width: 100px;
 height: 100px;
 background-color: blue;
 float: left;
}

#b
{
 width: 200px;
 height: 200px;
 display: block;
 border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<body>
 <div id=a></div>
 
 <img id=b src="https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/5cb44dcd4ebddfea3ede8c6d46b02795?s=328&d=identicon&r=PG&f=1">
</body>
```

Comment: It's worth pointing out that this is intuitive behavior when you consider the point of `float` in the first place, which was to wrap content around images like in magazine articles.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Several paragraphs after the one you quote, the spec says:

> The border box of a table, a block-level replaced element, or an element in the normal flow that establishes a new block formatting context (such as an element with 'overflow' other than 'visible') must not overlap the margin box of any floats in the same block formatting context as the element itself.

Although you've applied `display: block` to your image, being an image it's a replaced element, and therefore the float cannot intrude into its bounds.

Only non-replaced block boxes that don't establish block formatting contexts and are in the same flow as a float may ignore the float.<sup>1</sup> A block-level replaced element is not a block box, because a replaced element cannot be a block container box.<sup>2</sup>

---

<sup>1</sup> <sub>You're probably thinking, *that's a ridiculously specific statement*, and it is. It's why terms like "block element" are considered extremely vague in CSS parlance. Then again, it doesn't help that CSS itself defines almost equally vague terms like "block box" to specifically refer to boxes that are both block-level boxes and block container boxes.</sub>

<sup>2</sup> <sub>This does imply that "non-replaced block box" is somewhat of a tautology, which reinforces just how ridiculously specific that statement is.</sub>

Comment: Oh, that's unintuitive to me. What is the rationale behind replaced element and floats?

Comment: @PcAF: You'd have to ask the working group about that.

Answer (score 0):

[W3C](http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/REC-CSS2-20110607/visuren.html#block-boxes)
These are the two things that stuck out to me when viewing the W3C.  <strike>It's considering it as a line box.</strike>

> A floated box is shifted to the left or right until its outer edge touches the containing block edge or the outer edge of another float. If there is a line box, the outer top of the floated box is aligned with the top of the current line box.
>
> A line box is next to a float when there exists a vertical position that satisfies all of these four conditions: (a) at or below the top of the line box, (b) at or above the bottom of the line box, (c) below the top margin edge of the float, and (d) above the bottom margin edge of the float.

Comment: A block box cannot appear within a line box.